# How to not round durations

Tags: go, time, duration

I am attempting to clock the execution of a process and I need the value in seconds.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    startTime := time.Now()
    time.Sleep(1379 * time.Millisecond)

    elapsedTime := time.Since(startTime)
    fmt.Println(elapsedTime) //->1.379s

    secs := float64(elapsedTime / time.Second)
    fmt.Println(secs)//->1
    //desired output is: 1.379
}
```

I am looking for a way to have the time not NOT being rounded.
Here's the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/VLgKTpmkHPS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the [Seconds()](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration.Seconds) method:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    elapsedTime := 1379 * time.Millisecond
    fmt.Println(elapsedTime) //->1.379s

    secs := elapsedTime.Seconds()
    fmt.Println(secs)
}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/uK0-h4jEDhe).

Answer (score 0):

Epoc time to to convert the time to seconds

update :  Below code works ?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    startTime := time.Now()
    nanos := startTime.Unix()
    // fmt.Println(startTime)
    millis := nanos / 1000000
    elapsedInsecondsT := float64(millis)/float64(1000)
    fmt.Println( millis, elapsedInsecondsT )
}
```

courtesy : https://gobyexample.com/epoch

Comment: The reason I divide by time.Second is that the "s" goes away. I do this because if the execution time goes into the minutes I get something like 1m5s. Then I get an "m" in the number too.